# What is the use of Magnifying staffs ability?

Tags: magicka

I did not complete the main story yet, but I have the detective robe due to the DLC. With that robe comes the Magnifying staff, and its ability is to zoom-in into a certain area. What is the use of this ability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The magnifying action is only aesthetic and has no other uses. Instead the Detective Robe gives you access to few locations and magicks in The Stars Are Left DLC.